# 204 No Content response code when setting a property in Artifactory

Tags: httprequest, httpresponse, artifactory

Trying to add the property in maven local repository in JFrog Artifactory using Artifactory REST API but received the
response code
`HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` when using the below PUT method:

`Artifactory_url/api/storage/repo-name/abc.jar?properties=jiraID=DO1234&recursive=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` is the expected response.

You will receive `404 Not Found` if path doesn't exist.

You should be able to see the properties on the artifact in Artifactory.

Comment: Which path are you referring, I see the repo in artifactory.Please advise

Comment: You were setting the properties to the artifact in path repo-name/abc.jar.
Go to the artifact, click on the properties tab, and verify they were set.

Comment: Thank you, I can able to see now.